# By using Bootstrap 4, how to toggle a div whose parent div is hidden under the certain resolution?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, hidden

When it's on the large screen, I have a navigation div which contains another five sub divs serving as five different navigation sections, like

[image]

I gave the navigation div `class="d-none d-lg-block"` so that this whole thing will only show at large screen and above and hide when it's smaller than the large screen.

However, on the smaller screens, I have created another div that contains some buttons which I hope they could toggle those navigation sections, like

[image]

when I click on Div1, I want the content Item1 and Item2 in Div1 to be toggled.

But just giving the section an `id="div1"` and `class="navbar-toggler", data-toggle="collapse" and data-target="#div1"` wouldn't make this happen. I also tried giving the div `display: block` when it's at a smaller resolution to no avail.

I have a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/chenhang91/u8b9cwmw/

What could be a good way to solve this problem elegantly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided code it's not possible to show a menu in a parent, which is hidden explicitly with a class .container.d-none.d-lg-block.

I suggest you restructure the whole html:

1. there's no  need for extra submenu toggle divs .small-screen-div at all, toggling for submenus can be assigned to .nav-block-title. hence we move d-none.d-lg-block classes to the submenu themselves (changing d-lg-block to d-lg-inline-block accordingly)

   ```
   <div class="nav-block-section">
     <div class="nav-block-title d-inline-block ml-0"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#div3">Div3</a></div>
     <div class="collapse nav-block-navs d-none d-lg-inline-block" id="div3">
   <div class="pb-2">
     <a href="#">Item1</a>
     <a href="#">Item2</a>
     <a href="#">Item3</a>
     <a href="#">Item4</a>
   </div>
   <div>
     <a href="#">Item1</a>
     <a href="#">Item2</a>
     <a href="#">Item3</a>
     <a href="#">Item4</a>
   </div>
   ```
2. in this case data-toggle="collapse" need a small adjustment in css, to allow display switching no matter what media query is now.

   ```
    @media (max-width:991px) {
    .nav-block-navs.collapse.show {
      display:inline-block !important;
     }
   }
   ```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/u8b9cwmw/3/)

Comment: Oh thanks GL.awog! That's a smart way of solving this problem! So actually if we just hide the toggled div itself rather than hide the toggled sections as a whole (since you actually "moved" `d-none` from `nav-block-whole` to each `nav-block-navs`) **AND** set `.nav-block-navs.collapse.show` as `display:inline-block !important;`, we can still toggle them to show right?

Comment: yes, that right, in my example you can toggle them on any resolution

Comment: Nice! I managed to use your solution to solve my headache! Thanks again! :D